# Optimize MS Access Double SubQuery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, ms-access-2010

This MS Access query I'm building is very slow.  I am testing only one Month of data (One table driving this query with 28,577 records, 36 columns).

**Here is what I am trying to accomplish:**

I want to return the count of unique vehicles by Model that are sold in  specific transaction type (This database is not normalized, and is built from an excel sheet loaded into a table).

The first subquery exists because it is my understanding that in Access you cannot use the DISTINCT statement with an aggregate function.  So I needed to build a subquery to handle Count(DISTINCT VIN).

The second subquery is what I believe to be the culprit.  Each VIN may have many entries.  For example A Vehicle might have been sold using one of the Transaction Categories I am counting, then Cancelled, and resold into one of the transaction categories that I don't want to count.  This would produce three records for this VIN:

1. Sale into transaction category that I thought I wanted to count
2. Cancel of that first sale
3. Re-sold into a a transaction category that I don't want to count

The 2nd subquery checks to see if a VIN has a "cancelled Sale" record and then does not include the first Sale in the count.

Hopefully I explained this well, and someone can offer me a potential solution to speed up this query.

THANKS

### Query

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Sales Month Start Date] DATETIME, [Enter Sales Month End Date] 
DATETIME; 

SELECT DSTNCT_COUNT.trans      AS Trans, 
       DSTNCT_COUNT.mdl        AS Model, 
       Count(DSTNCT_COUNT.cnt) AS VIN_COUNT 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT new_bbss.vin              AS cNt, 
                        new_bbss.[model category] AS MDL, 
                        new_bbss.[trans category] AS Trans 
        FROM   new_bbss 
        WHERE  ( ( ( new_bbss.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE 'Individual' 
                   AND ( new_bbss.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE 'Corporate' 
                   AND ( new_bbss.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE 'Cancel' 
                   AND ( new_bbss.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE 'Partners' 
                   AND ( new_bbss.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE 'Special' 
                   AND ( new_bbss.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE 'Employee' 
                   AND ( new_bbss.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE 'Mobile' 
                   AND ( new_bbss.[trans category] ) NOT LIKE 'JLR FLEET' ) 
                   AND ( ( new_bbss.[retailer code] ) LIKE 'R*' ) ) 
                   AND new_bbss.[trans date] BETWEEN [enter sales month start date] 
                                             AND 
                                                 [enter sales month end date] 
                   AND new_bbss.vin NOT IN(SELECT new_bbss.vin 
                                           FROM   new_bbss 
                                           WHERE  new_bbss.[trans category] LIKE 
                                              'CancelVIP*' 
                                               OR new_bbss.[trans category] LIKE 
                                                  'CancelDealer Local*' 
                                               OR new_bbss.[trans category] LIKE 
                                                  'CancelLoaner*' 
                                               OR new_bbss.[trans category] LIKE 
                                                  'CancelAlive*'))
       AS DSTNCT_COUNT 
GROUP  BY trans, mdl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MsAccess is supposed to be slower on NOT IN than on NOT EXISTS. I don't know whether this is true, but you can try anyway. Moreover you can move this restriction from your WHERE clause to a HAVING clause, as vin is in the GROUP BY clause. This may reduce the times MsAccess has to look this up.

```
select [model category], [trans category], count(*)
from
(
  select [model category], [trans category], vin
  from new_bbss
  where [trans category] not like 'Individual' 
    and [trans category] not like 'Corporate' 
    and [trans category] not like 'Cancel' 
    and [trans category] not like 'Partners' 
    and [trans category] not like 'Special' 
    and [trans category] not like 'Employee' 
    and [trans category] not like 'Mobile' 
    and [trans category] not like 'JLR FLEET' 
    and [retailer code] like 'R*'
    and [trans date] between [enter sales month start date] 
                         and [enter sales month end date] 
  group by [model category], [trans category], vin
  having not exists
  (
    select *
    from new_bbss unwanted
    where unwanted.vin = new_bbss.vin
    and  
    (    unwanted.[trans category] like 'CancelVIP*' 
      or unwanted.[trans category] like 'CancelDealer Local*' 
      or unwanted.[trans category] like 'CancelLoaner*' 
      or unwanted.[trans category] like 'CancelAlive*'
    )
  )
) matches
group by [model category], [trans category];
```

BTW: There should be an index on vin, so MsAccess can look up its records quickly.